# Can somebody please please help me translate this...?

Tags: translation

[image]

Can you please help me translate the writing on this piece of paper? I've been working on this for the past four hours by looking up the characters one by one and using translation websites and Google translate, but it's so hard for me because I'm  not that familiar with the Japanese language. It came from inside a wooden box with a pair of chopsticks in it that was given to me by a Japanese guy (an acquaintance from work).I don't think it's that important - it's probably just a set of instructions or something - but I am really really really curious about what it says.

Based on my research, the first two characters on the topmost sentence mean 'lacquerware', and sentence number one I think says something about the intended purpose of the item? That's about as far as I got with google translate... the rest of the translations didn't make any sense to me at all.

Comment: It's a bunch of caution text. 'Please do not use for non-intended purposes'.

Answer (score 3):

> 漆器をお使いいただく上でご注意
>
> １．製品本来の用途、使用目的に添って正しくお使い下さい。誤ったご使用は製品の破損や身体に危険を及ぼす場合があります。
>
> ２．体質により、ごくまれに漆等の塗料でかぶれることがあります。異常を感じたときは、ご使用をお止めいただき専門医にご相談ください。
>
> ３．直火、電子レンジ、乾燥機、食器洗浄機、たわし等でのご使用しないで下さい。
>
> ４．塗りの表面を、冒すような化学繊維、薬品等はご使用しないで下さい。
>
> ５．割れ、ひびが入った場合は、お早めに新しい製品をご使用下さい。

Lacquerware usage warnings.

1. Please use properly according to its the intended use. Incorrect usage may damage the product.
2. If you develop any rashes, discoloration, or other symptoms due to contact with the lacquer, please see a doctor immediately.
3. Do not use with open fire, microwave, dryer, dishwasher, scrubbing brush, or similar.
4. Do not use apply chemical fibers or other chemical products to the surface of the product.
5. If cracked, please replace as soon as possible.

Comment: Why did I get downvoted?

Comment: ダウンボートしたの私じゃないんですけど、２番は、「[漆]{うるし}」で、手とか肌とかが「かぶれる」かもしれないので、かぶれたら病院に行け、ってことです。